# Java alternative for empty overridden method in sub class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the following class hierarchy:

**`BaseActivity`:**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   protected abstract void bindView();
}
```

**`ASubActivity`:**

```
public class ASubActivity extends BaseActivity {
  @Override
  protected void bindView() {
    //No implementation
  }
}
```

**`BSubActivity`:**

```
public class BSubActivity extends BaseActivity {

  private Toolbar toolbar;

  @Override
  protected void bindView() {
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  }

  ...
}
```

I find this to be a bit ugly. I would rather just not have the `bindView()` method in the `ASubActivity`. Is there a best practice way to do this?

**NOTE:** the `BaseActity` does contain some other abstract methods that are used by both subclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to put `bindView()` in an interface instead of `BaseActivity` and have only `BSubActivity` implement that interface:

```
public interface BindViewInterface{
    protected void bindView();
}
```

Then there would be no need to have `bindView()` `BSubActivity`.

Another way would be to not make `bindView()` an abstract method:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void bindView() {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a more general java problem than being specific to android.  All abstract methods MUST be implemented which makes the code messy.

The only other alternative is to implement the `// do nothing` version in the parent class (`BaseActivity` in your case).  You don't have to make it abstract just because it does nothing in an abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   protected void bindView() {}
}
```

ASubActivity:

```
public class ASubActivity extends BaseActivity {
   // Nothing to see here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case you could make your bindView()-method not abstract:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void bindView() {
    }
}
```

In this case you do not have to override the method in your `ASubActivity`. But you can override the method in your `BSubActivity`.